# Updating gridview's drop down lists using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gridview with several fields. Fields in question are PreviousPoints, GainedPoints, TotalPoints. In the edit mode PreviousPoints is not editable, just data bind, GainedPoints is a drop down list and Total Points is a Drop Down List.

When GainedPoints drop down list selected value changes, I need the TotalPoint selected value to be set to the value of PreviousPoints control + GainedPoints selected value.

But, I cannot refresh the whole page using post back.
How can it be done using JavaScript or something similar without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onselect() function in javascript and have your computations there.